# Nginx root switch based on path for multiple vue apps

Tags: vue.js, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

Lets say I have 2 routes `/` and `/first` and both are supposed to route to different vue apps.

I have the root switching working ok, the issue is when you go to `/first` the vue app cannot load any of the javascript files or css files because they go to `/js` or `/css` instead of `/first/js` or `/first/css`

The two location blocks I have are very simple like this:

```
    location /first {
        alias  /home/first/dist;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location / {
        alias  /home/second/dist;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

The js and css files are loaded in normally like `/js/chunk-vendors.deb8a740.js`. I this that its not working because nginx is stripping the `/first` on the response because if I change the import to `/first/js/chunk-vendors.deb8a740.js` the app loads.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this for my own case at least so I'll share what I ended up with.

I added a `vue.config.js` which contains a public path, so all the imports in the dist folder turned from `/js` to `/first/js`

Which is all I needed for my case.

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/first/'
}
```